# Exchange 2016: high amount of send connectors problematic?

Tags: email-server, exchange-2016

On an Exchange 2016 we would like to configure different security settings for approx. 250 Domains (Limit non delivery reports to these). A solution might be to configure a separate send connector for each of these domains.

- Is there a problem configuring this amount of send connectors - maybe performance problems?
- Is there a better way to achieve this than more send connectors?

Thanks for any advice or links concerning this.

An extensive search of the Internet doesn't give any useful results.

Comment: "Is there a problem" - did you *test* this? Does a mail that you send to a reasonably responsive destination arrive within the second, or are the noticeable delays?

Comment: "Limit non delivery reports" - why do you send a number of reports significant enough to warrant any special treatment in the first place?

Comment: We don't send a significant amount of NDRs out. We want to prevent backscatter and information leackage due to security concerns.

Comment: Does the method help you to protect information? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/create-test-tune-dlp-policy?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research, there seems no official blog on limits of send connectors we can configure in exchange server.

```
On an Exchange 2016 we would like to configure different security settings for approx. 250 Domains (Limit non delivery reports to these)
```

Maybe you can use transport rule to configure NDR. For example:[image]